# prove that $\phi_a: C_n \to C_n $ is bijective $\iff$ a is coprime to $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\phi_a$ be a homomorphism with $\phi_a(x) = x^a$. prove that $\phi_a: C_n \to C_n $ is bijective $\iff$ a is coprime to $n$

The proof I have here has:

$|\text{Im}(\phi_a)| = \text{ord}(x^a) = \text{ord}(\phi_a (x))$ and we know that $\text{ord}(x^a) = n \iff \text{ a is coprime to n }$ hence we get the result.

My confusion is how we got that $|\text{Im}(\phi_a)| = \text{ord}(x^a)$

Comment: That's a bit confusing, since $x$ was originally used as a general element of $C_n$, while the statement $|\mathrm{Im}(\phi_a)|=\mathrm{ord}(\phi_a(x))$ is only true if $x$ is a generator of $C_n$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Glad you said that because that's the only way I made it work - the solutions make no mentions of $x$ being a generator, though

Comment: It is possible that, when defining $\phi_a$, that $x$ there was supposed to be the generator, too. Basically, any $\phi:C_n\to G$ is entirely determined by $\phi(g)$ where $g$ is a generator of $C_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Because $C_n$ is finite, $\phi_a$ is bijective iff $\phi_a$ is injective iff $\phi_a$ is surjective.

> If $(a,n)=1$, then $\phi_a$ is injective:

Write $au+nv=1$. Let $x\in\ker \phi_a$. Then $x=x^1=x^{au+nv}=(x^a)^u (x^n)^v=1$.

> If $\phi_a$ is surjective, then $(a,n)=1$:

Let $g$ be a generator of $C_n$ and let $x$ be such that $x^a=g$.
Write $x=g^b$. Then $g=x^a=g^{ab}$. This implies that $1\equiv ab \bmod n$ and so $(a,n)=1$.